# Django formatting input contents

Tags: django

I am using simplemde markdown editor,which adds the markdown elements to the user contents, my problem is when user inputs the below line  , with stakedit's block (** text **) and code (4 spaces ) I want to display  it as below format

**This program is not working**

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
  cout<<"Hello world"
}
```

but when I save the contents and escape it, I get the following output

**This program is not working** #include int main() { cout<<"Hello world" }

in unformatted manner, how do I display it as formatted
Here's the code I am using to display :

```
{% block content %}
{% if question_detail %}
<h4><small> {{ question_detail.title }} </small></h4>
 <pre> {{ question_detail.get_description|escape |linebreaksbr }} </pre>
{% else %}
<small > an error occured </small>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

get_description in models.py

```
def get_description(self):
    return mark_safe (markdown(self.description))
```

Comment: Try to remove the `|escape |linebreaksbr` filters be cause you already mark the markdown output as safe

Comment: did that ....but still the code is getting printed in unformatted manner .

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
{% block content %}
{% if question_detail %}
<h4><small> {{ question_detail.title }} </small></h4>
 <pre> {{ question_detail.get_description|safe }} </pre>
{% else %}
<small > an error occured </small>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
def get_description(self):
    return markdown(self.description)
```